# Simple Hash replacement for MD5

Tags: c#, hash

I have a database where images (byte[] - typically less than 100k) are stored in a table.
There is a Hash column in the table which stores the MD5 hash of the image bytes.
No security implications here, it is used only by the application as a quick check to see if the image already exists.

The MD5Cng class has disappeared from .NET 5 so I want to replace the Hash values now in preparation to moving to .NET 6 later.

What is a simple algorithm that will take a byte[] and return byte[16]?

Comment: Take the first 16 bytes of a different hash (pick your favourite), or use something like a CRC

Comment: I'd be truly surprised if MD5 has been removed from .NET 5.

Comment: Yep, [still there in .NET 6 preview 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5?view=net-5.0)

Comment: `static readonly MD5 md5CSP = new MD5Cng();`
was the line in code which no longer compiles. and I seemingly misunderstood that deprecated doesn't mean removed.
Thanks for the quick replies - I'll work out what the replacement is.

Comment: `MD5Cng` specifically was removed in .NET Core, but you should use `static readonly MD5 md5CSP = MD5.Create();`

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5cng?view=netframework-4.8) to use some variation of the [Secure Hashing Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms) instead of MD5. However, .NET 5 *does* come with an [implementation of the MD5-algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5?view=net-5.0).